# Heroku Schema load: Permission denied for database "postgres" User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm trying to deploy my Rails app to Heroku, and I now want to load my schema. I get the following error:

```
Running `bundle exec rake db:schema:load` attached to terminal... up, run.1533
rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

Which is weird because `postgres` is not the database it should connect to. The database URL, which is available to the app via ENV, has the right values, and the long apparently random name `d3kwlkwlwjwljetc...`.

Searching for this message gives me people who are trying to drop or reset the DB, which is not what I'm doing.

- I have 0 rows
- I tried `pg:reset`, even removed and put back the database. No avail.
- I'm not doing `db:drop`, just `db:schema:load`

I'm dumbfounded. Why can't my app connect?

Edit: Apparently, I can't `schema:load`, but I can migrate all my migrations over. Why is that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It appears that this is an issue in Rails itself - there is a discussion regarding it at https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/17945 - it seems that there's a commit (https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks.rb#L77) that is connecting to the posgres database which isn't permitted on Heroku so fails.

In short, for the moment use db:migrate until the issue is resolved.

Comment: Thank you John! Hopefully this can help others who run into the same thing. It seems the patch has been released in 4.1.9 and 4.2.0.