# Creating postgres database on Heroku with Rails 4 error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, heroku

**PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR**

I am trying to deploy a Rails 4 app on Heroku with a postgres database. I have precompiled assets, but now when I run:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

I get this error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" ADD COLUMN "invited_by_user_id" integer
rake aborted!
```

**Commonly suggested solutions on Stack Overflow:**

I have tried resetting the database with:

```
heroku pg:reset
```

The database resets, but I still can't run db:migrate.

I have also tried:

```
heroku run db:setup
```

but I get an error that says:

```
FATAL:  permission denied for database "postgres"
DETAIL:  User does not have CONNECT privilege.
```

I was using Rails 4.1.8, and saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846844/heroku-schema-load-permission-denied-for-database-postgres-user) which suggested maybe I needed to update to rails 4.1.9 or above, but even now that I'm using Rails 4.2.2, no luck.

**Additional possibly relevant info:**

Connecting to the postgres database on heroku with

```
heroku pg:psql
```

then listing the databases with '\l' gives me a long list of databases with cryptic names:

```
 Name      |     Owner      | Encoding |   Collate   |    Ctype    |         Access privileges         
----------------+----------------+----------+-------------+-------------+-----------------------------------
 d100o5a2gii5he | rdxtahlqikernc | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | rdxtahlqikernc=CTc/rdxtahlqikernc
 d102ehvv3umqam | ibuffadisyolrb | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | ibuffadisyolrb=CTc/ibuffadisyolrb
 d103n2kea6j5sa | tzzkfcinullytw | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | tzzkfcinullytw=CTc/tzzkfcinullytw
 d10597iiu347nk | eltovdzaxajtiu | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | eltovdzaxajtiu=CTc/eltovdzaxajtiu
 d108g0imdgn865 | pvzysfivyhcnaa | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | pvzysfivyhcnaa=CTc/pvzysfivyhcnaa
...

 dvs2j8tkv153m  | zjefhzzizozpwy | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | zjefhzzizozpwy=CTc/zjefhzzizozpwy
 postgres       | postgres       | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template0      | postgres       | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | =c/postgres                      +
        |                |          |             |             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1      | postgres       | UTF8     | en_US.UTF-8 | en_US.UTF-8 | postgres=CTc/postgres
(4787 rows)
```

I'm not sure exactly how to interpret that.

I am relatively new new to Rails, but have successfully setup several databases on Heroku in the past. Following the Heroku documentation hasn't helped, and I'm not sure where to go from here.

How can I get db:migrate to complete without errors?

**NOTE: I solved this just after posting. See answer below.**

Comment: You need to add invited_by_user_id to users table

Comment: I already have a column in my users table for invited_by_user_id

Comment: Can we see your migration for the `users` table?

Comment: Apologies...I figured it out! I need to run db:schema:load, but for some reason couldn't do it until I upgraded to 4.2.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minutes after posting this question I figured it out, and I'm hoping this might help someone else out.

The solution was to upgrade from Rails 4.1.8 to Rails 4.2.2.

Then run

```
heroku run rake db:schema:load
```

before

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

For some reason that wouldn't run for my project with Rails 4.1.8. So, after upgrading to Rails 4.2.2, I ran the schema load and migrate commands with no errors.

Comment: 3 sleepless nights, hours of debugging, resetting database more than 10 times. Just to find this answer. Sir , you are my savior. I salute you.